# onclickListener for actionbar elements

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

I have two different layouts for my actionbar, each one triggered by the other. for the first one i can easy declare onclicklister in the oncreate method. For the second one i have to associate the listener inside the first onclicklistener because is the right time to do it, when it has been created. The code work for only an iteration, but when i click the button in the second layout, the trigger for the first one dont work because it is associated with the oncreate method.

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            action = getSupportActionBar();

            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33000000"));
            action.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

            action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_button);


                      ImageButton searchButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_form);
        ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_button);
            }
        });
    }
});

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


search_form:   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_form"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:hint="search"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/pipe"
            android:background="#00000000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

search_button:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="le ultime novità"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/_search"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using custom views to emulate the functionality that you would already get if you used a `SearchView` widget and used `onCreateOptionsMenu` to set up the items in the action bar.